# I want to apply a threshold to pixels in image using python. Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, threshold, image-thresholding

I want to generate the output that is a threshold. And my error:

> img_thres = n_pix[y, x]
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

img = cv2.imread("cicek.png",0)
img_rgb = cv2.imread("cicek.png")

h = img.shape[0]
w = img.shape[1]

img_thres= []
n_pix = 0
# loop over the image, pixel by pixel
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        # threshold the pixel
        pixel = img[y, x]
        if pixel < 0.5:
            n_pix = 0
        img_thres = n_pix[y, x]

cv2.imshow("cicek", img_thres)
```

Comment: `n_pix` is always 0. What do you expect `0[y,x]` to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are already using **OpenCV**, you may as well use its optimised SIMD code to do your thresholding. Not only is it shorter and easier to maintain, it is also miles faster. It looks like this:

```
_, thres = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Yes, that's it! That replaces all your code.

---

**Benchmarking and demo**

Borrowing heavily from other answers, I put together:

- a method using double `for` loops,
- a Numpy method, and
- the OpenCV method I am suggesting

and ran some timing tests inside **IPython**. So, I saved this code as `thresh.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def method1(img):
    """Double loop over pixels"""
    h = img.shape[0]
    w = img.shape[1]

    img_thres= np.zeros((h,w))
    # loop over the image, pixel by pixel
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            # threshold the pixel
            pixel = img[y, x]
            img_thres[y, x] = 0 if pixel < 128 else pixel
    return img_thres

def method2(img):
    """Numpy indexing"""
    img_thres = img
    img_thres[ img < 128 ] = 0
    return img_thres

def method3(img):
    """OpenCV thresholding"""
    _, thres = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
    return thres

img = cv2.imread("gradient.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Then, I started **IPython** and did:

```
%load thresh.py
```

Then, I timed the three methods:

```
%timeit method1(img)
81 ms ± 545 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit method2(img)
24.5 µs ± 818 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit method3(img)
3.03 µs ± 79.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note that the first result is in milliseconds whereas the other two are in microseconds. The Numpy version is 3,300 times faster than the for loops, and that the OpenCV version is 27,000 times faster!!!

You can check they produce the same result by totting up the differences in the images like this:

```
np.sum(method1(img)-method3(img))
0.0
```

Start image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote any answer that does proper benchmarking. :)

Comment: You told me so well. Thank you for your help and your explain :)

Comment: My pleasure - glad it worked for you. Remember, questions, and answers, are free so come back if you get stuck again :-) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

To apply a threshold to an image just do this:

```
img_thres = img >= 0.5
```

You don't need any loops for thresholding.

If, as it seems from your code, you don't want to threshold, but instead set all pixels with a value below 0.5 to 0, you can use the binary image that results from a threshold for "logical indexing" as follows:

```
img_thres = img
img_thres[ img < 0.5 ] = 0
```

Code that uses the NumPy vectorized operations is always more efficient that code that explicitly loops over each array element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

img = cv2.imread("cicek.png",0)
img_rgb = cv2.imread("cicek.png")

h = img.shape[0]
w = img.shape[1]

img_thres= np.zeros((h,w))
n_pix = 0
# loop over the image, pixel by pixel
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        # threshold the pixel
        pixel = img[y, x]
        if pixel < 128: # because pixel value will be between 0-255.
            n_pix = 0
        else:
            n_pix = pixel

        img_thres[y, x] = n_pix 

cv2.imshow("cicek", img_thres)
```

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I edited the code and it works fine now. Thanks @CrisLuengo.