# How to change Pixeldata with Python on a gpu

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, gpu

I'm currently working on Image classification with cnn's. But in order to train the model in a way that makes sense I wanted to prpare the images before training. In my case the pictures are all gray and I want to check every Pixel value and if its higher then a certain value it should change the value of the Pixel.

For the CNN I'm already working with tensorflow-gpu which decreased the training time from 30 to 2 minutes. For the preparation of the images I didn't get further because I'm not sure how to transform t´for example the Cuda Cast tutorials to my specific problem.

If neccesary:
I'm using the GT62VR 7RE Dominator Pro from MSI with an 7th Gen CPU Geforce GTX 1070 gpu, intel CORE i7 and windows 10.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random
import pickle

DataDir = "C:/Users/ARVR/Documents/Machine_Learning/JobImages" #location of my images

CATEGORIES = ["Fehler", "kein_Fehler_2"] #the different categories

IMG_SIZE = 600 #new Image size

training_data = [] #prepared Dataset

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES: #Go into the different Folders
        path = os.path.join(DataDir, category) #location of images of this category
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category) #remamber the category
        for img in os.listdir(path): #take an image
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #create array of pixle data
                for i in range (len (img_array)):
                    for j in range (len (img_array[i])):
                        if img_array[i][j] >= 90: #check every pixel for a cirtain value
                            img_array[i][j] = 255
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) #resize image
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num]) #save in prepared Dataset
            except Exception as e:
                   pass

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data) #shuffle the training data

X = []
Y = []

for features, label in training_data: #save Pixel array and category seperatly
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,1)

pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb") #save both as file
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("Y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(Y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

I need to have a pretty high image size like 600 x 600 or higher. But if I run the script on cpu it takes forever to go through every picture (about 1500). Can I use Vactorize, cuda accelerate or sth. like this for my script? Or is there an easy way to make this script run on my gpu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712937/i-want-to-apply-a-threshold-to-pixels-in-image-using-python-where-did-i-make-a) (StackOverflow) can help you.

With cv2:

```
_, thres = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Apart from the cv2 built-in function, i like this simple answer:

```
img_thres = img

#set all pixels below 90 to 0
img_thres[ img < 90 ] = 0
```

Quote from the autor:
"*Code that uses the NumPy vectorized operations is always more efficient that code that explicitly loops over each array element.*"

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know that it could be so easy :P